How to filter out numbers with n digits in a dataframe in R?
In my DATA below, I'm trying to subset()/dplyr::filter() the INs that are 5 digits long.
I'm using the following without success. Is there a better solution?
Tried: subset(DATA, nchar(sub('\\.[0-9]+', '', as.character(DATA$IN)))==5)
DATA <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="
ID  IN
1   012
2   1234
3   222222
4   1359764
5   123
6   00441")


Great question - Are your actual data read in using read.table or something else like read.csv? There are ways using these functions to coerce the variable into a character. At the moment, it’s reading it in as a number so dropping the leading zeros

@jpsmith, thanks. I'm not using read.table! I convert the values to characters and then read them specifically to guard against the dropping of leading zeros. I actually wish there was a way to keep the values as numerics.

How about this?
DATA <- read.table(header=TRUE, colClasses = c("character", "character"), text="
ID  IN
1   012
2   1234
3   222222
4   1359764
5   123
6   00441")

DATA %>% mutate(num_chars = nchar(IN)) %>% filter(num_chars == 5)


DATA |>
  filter(stringr::str_length(IN) == 5)

#  ID    IN
#1  6 00441

where
DATA <- read.table(header=TRUE, colClasses = "character", text="
ID  IN
1   012
2   1234
3   222222
4   1359764
5   123
6   00441")

> DATA
  ID      IN
1  1     012
2  2    1234
3  3  222222
4  4 1359764
5  5     123
6  6   00441


A base R using subset
> subset(DATA, subset = nchar(IN)==5)
  ID    IN
6  6 00441

Using [
> DATA[with(DATA, nchar(IN)==5), ]
  ID    IN
6  6 00441

Using dplyr´s filter without creating a new variable:
> filter(DATA, nchar(IN) == 5)
  ID    IN
1  6 00441

